# CAML Query results every time 0 items

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, caml

I try to filter items in the list by using caml. 
The List contains elements that matches the Filter.

The code:

```
enter code here

SPQuery qry = new SPQuery();
            qry.Query =
            @"   <Where>
                  <Eq>
                     <FieldRef Name='Gesch_x00e4_ftsbereich' />
                     <Value Type='Text'>FHC</Value>
                  </Eq>
               </Where>";
            qry.ViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name='Gesch_x00e4_ftsbereich' /><FieldRef Name='Dokument' />";
            SPList akten = web.Lists.TryGetList(ListNameAkten);

            // get the items
            SPListItemCollection aktenCollection = akten.GetItems(qry);
```

Now when I execute the query like obove, I get a resultset of 0. When I remove the ViewFields Parameter, I got hte same result.

What I'm doing wrong?
Doesn't Sharepoint Online (365) doesn't support caml?!

Comment: SharePoint 365 supports CAML. Have you try to do the same query with a tool like a caml designer: http://www.biwug.be/

Comment: Just to double-check: Are you querying a text field?

Comment: Hi this field ist a normal textfield. And the value already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my goodness I  got the solution...

The Documentlist contains subfolders and I must recurse the Items in it.

```
  SPQuery qry = new SPQuery();
            qry.Query = string.Format(@"   <Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' />  <Value Type='Text'>{1}</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>0</Value></Eq></And></Where>", FieldNameBusinesArea, businessAreaToFiler);
            qry.IncludeMandatoryColumns = true;
            qry.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'";


            // get the items
            SPListItemCollection aktenCollection = akten.GetItems(qry);
```

Now I got the results. 
Thx alot